# Updating QLineEdit on QPushButton click in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I currently have the following QLineEdit:

```
self.lineEdit_15.setText(_translate("Dialog", "email"))
```

I am trying to update it with the following QPushButton:

```
self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "update"))
```

Ideally, I'd like to get user data and store it as a variable. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a look at `signals and slots` in PyQt.

For example, when a button is clicked it triggers a clicked signal that you can connect to a slot. This slot can do the stuff you need

```
self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.mySlotFunction)

#Slot that stores lineEdit text in myVar string
def mySlotFunction():
    myVar = self.lineEdit_15.text()
```

Comment: The old-style signal and slot syntax isn't supported in pyqt5. Use `self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.mySlotFunction)`.